# FSRM Quota in DFS - Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, dfs, dfs-r

We have two servers DFS1 and DFS2 which are configured as target for DFS Namespace and DFS Replication. Namespace is `\\Domain.com\Files\Users\User1` whose target are `\\DFS1\Users\User1` (local path `D:\User1`) and `\\DFS2\Users\User1`. We have also configured the DFS Replication for those paths.

In the DFS1 server, I have added a 1GB hard quota using the local path (`D:\User1`) in File Server Resource Manager.

1. When I map network drive using `\\DFS1\Users\User1` path, it shows the total size as 1GB.
2. When I map network drive using `\\Domain.com\Files\Users\User1` path, it shows the total size as the drive size which is 922GB.
3. When I map network drive using `\\DFS2\Users\User1` path, it shows the total size as the drive size which is 922GB. It looks like the quota is not getting replicate with DFS.

How do I make FSRM Quota to work in DFS Namespace and DFS Replication?

Answer (score 1):

FSRM quotas are independent of DFS. When using the DFS path for a replicated share, you will see the quota of ultimately whatever file share server you get routed as configured within DFS management. You can test by disabling the target where you don't have a quota set.

The way I have always managed this in the past is simply applying your quota on both share servers. You can build some automation around it using dirquota or the new PowerShell cmdlets.